# How do I navigate an import/compatibility error for python powerpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, version, python-pptx

I have a very simple script below

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation()
print('finish')
```

This causes the following error

```
    from pptx import Presentation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pptx/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pptx.api import Presentation  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pptx/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .package import Package
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pptx/package.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pptx.opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pptx/opc/package.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pptx.compat import is_string, Mapping
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pptx/compat/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    Container = collections.Container
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Container'
```

I am aware that python-pptx module does not support the latest version of python 3.11 as outlined in this forum here https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/863
What is the easiest way to navigate this?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
import collections 
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation()
print('finish')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.